# When putting jQuery DOM in a variable it loses functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

In case of this DOM:

```
<div class="elem" data-click></div>
<script>$('data-click').on('click', function(){ alert('test'); })</script>
```

And then put the jquery DOM in a variable like so:

```
var jDom = $('.elem');
```

And then try to append it like so:

```
$('.some-container').append(jDom);
```

It won't react on a click anymore. Why is that, and how can I solve? I know

```
$('body').on('.elem', 'click', function(){
    alert('test');
});
```

Would work, but I don't like to use to many triggers on body.

Comment: first look .on('.elem', 'click' should be  .on('click','.elem',

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/07z2teqa/1/ - only problem is `$('[data-click]')`

Comment: are you calling `jDom.remove()` anywhere?

Comment: `$('.some-container').append(jDom).bind('click',function(){});`

Answer (score -1):

Your final piece of code should be like this:

```
$('body').on('click', '.elem', function(){
    alert('test');
});
```

You had your selector `.elem` passed as the first argument, when it should have been the second argument to `.on()`

Like so: `.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )`

See here for more information: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: I have no idea why I was down voted here. It appears OP has gone awol too.

Answer (score -2):

I think you made a little mistake , change

```
$('body').on('.elem', 'click', function(){
    alert('test');
});
```

to

```
$('body').on('click', '.elem', function(){
    alert('test');
});
```

Ref : http://api.jquery.com/on/